# Updating SDK in an app without effecting client /app

Tags: android, ios, sdk, analytics, ads

I want to test various marketing analytics or referral tracking SDKs for my app. Is there a solution that will allow me to integrate all these SDKs one by one without having to update my client side app?

Essentially I want to ensure users don't have to update the app each time I choose a new service to track campaigns or referrals.

Segment.io seems to do something similar for website. Is their a service that works for apps?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you ADD new libraries to your client side code, your app will have to be updated.

A traditional way to solve your problem would be to integrate all the SDKs you want and remotely select the campaign that you want to run.

Suppose if you want to your app to have Flurry and Apsalar, both of these would need to be integrated first and then on each run, you can tell your app which of these should be run.

Hope it helps.